# How would I go about proving this approximation?

Tags: approximation

I was just playing around in desmos and I think I found something that approximates Lambert W for whole numbers.

$$f(x)=a(\int_{0}^{1}(\sum_{n=1}^{x}t^n-1)dt)+b$$

Where $a\approx0.765424$
And $b\approx0.944602$

$a$ and $b$ were achieved through linearization, plugging $xe^x$ in for x.

Please point me in the right direction for proofing or disproving that as $x \to \infty$  $f(x) \to W(x)$

Comment: You're effectively saying that the Lambert W function can be well approximated by a linear function of $\ln{(x)}$. But it's well known that $W(x)\sim\ln{(x)}$ so this is not surprising.

Comment: @Peter sorry I didn’t actually know that. Does ln(x) get closer to W(x) the higher x gets?

Comment: @CoderBoy It depends on what you mean by closer. The difference $\ln{(x)}-W(x)\to\infty$ but the ratio $W(x)/\ln{(x)}\to1$.

Comment: @Peter I’m actually interested in the difference and not the ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting post.

In fact
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{x}(t^n-1)dt=\psi (x+2)+\gamma -2$$

Looking at the empirical model
$$W(x)=a + b f(x)$$ for $0 \leq x \leq 10^6$ by steps of $10$, we obtain with $(R^2=0.999875)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.174690 & 0.000366 & \{0.173973, 0.175408\} \\
 b & 0.903778 & 0.000032 & \{0.903715, 0.903840\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Woah! Maybe better constants could get that R^2 much better. I assume I should compare (e^x+2)+−2 to W(xe^x) to get those better constants, and then see if anything interesting arises that could help with a proof. Thanks!

Comment: @CoderBoy. I think that you are forgetting that $W(x e^x)=x$.

Comment: no, sorry, might’ve been badly worded. I was going to use linearization to get a new a and b and see if they are a ratio of or are any known constants to help with a proof.